# Constant check mark

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

In my UItableview i just want make first four rows chemarked by default?How can i achieve this?Here my code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[am.genar addObject:[ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSLog(@"array content%@",[ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);   
if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) 
{
    thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}    
}
- (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   return UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

cellrowarindexpath method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.textLabel.text = [ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        // Configure the cell...

if(indexPath.row<4)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
return cell;
}
```

Please help me to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if(indexPath.row < 4) //considering that you need FIRST four rows to be checkmarked by default
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

return cell;
}
```

Let me know if I didn't understand your query properly. I'll make amendments accordingly. Happy coding :)

Comment: @iosdev  u will have to decide which four rows u have to checkmark? +10

Comment: @Anshuk Garg i did the coding its not showing 4 rows checked,not only in that i can able select four rows only.Can you please comment

Comment: can you please post your code of method - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Comment: cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; this disables cell selection.

Comment: @AnshukGarg then also its not working,Not only i show the table data from array ,Can i want to change any thing in `cell.textLabel.text = [ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`